# Very basic rewrite rule in Wordpress

Tags: php, url-rewriting, wordpress

It looked that easy. But still I fail writing a URL rewrite rule. The actual rule should be more complex but even the following very basic test rule does not work:

```
add_action('init', 'my_url_rewrite'));

function my_url_rewrite()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('test', 'index.php?page_id=96', 'top');
}
```

I expected this to do the following... when requesting the URL `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/test` it should actually open the page `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/index.php?page_id=96`.

Instead I get an error page telling my the request ressource wasn't found. I tried out a lot but it does not work. Seems I am doing a very basic mistake.

The "page_id" based URL is correct, it works when calling it directly. Also I would later move the flush line into plugin activation and deactivation hooks, this is only for testing.

Comment: Is this is your full code? Tried so far?

Comment: No. I now added the code how it is called. See above. I tried using it with flush, I tried using bottom, I tried different pattern. But since this simple thing fails I am a little out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found it. When placing the flush_rules() call after add_rewrite_rule() it works.

Darn. Actually I tried this first since it was described this way in API documentation. Probably I changed two things at the same time and came to the wrong conclusions. Sorry.

So I will do something like this on activation of the plugin:

```
add_rewrite_rule('test', 'index.php?page_id=96', 'top');
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

And this on deactivation:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

I suppose this is ok?

What still massively irritates me is the fact that [flush_rewrite_rules();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) and [$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules) have separate descriptions in the WP codex but when looking in the WP sources they are exactly the same thing. This is pretty confusing. The descriptions and examples are even different and they are not referencing each other. Why is this?